# Combine the results of two queries into one

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database, mysql-workbench

I am trying to make the following query in MySQL:

**Find the IDs of the suppliers that supply all the parts in red or green.**

The structure of the tables would be this:

```
proveedores(ID: int (PK), nombre: nvarchar, direccion: nvarchar)
partes(ID: int (PK), nombre: nvarchar, color: nvarchar)
catalogo(proveedores_ID: int (FK), partes_ID: int (FK), costo: double)
```

And I have managed to make a querys that allows me to see the IDs of the suppliers that distribute all the parts of red or green as the case may be.

The query using "red" or "Green" is this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.proveedores_ID FROM fabrica.catalogo C
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                  SELECT P.ID FROM fabrica.partes P
                  WHERE P.color = "red" AND ( NOT EXISTS (
                                                           SELECT C1.proveedores_ID FROM fabrica.catalogo C1
                                                           WHERE C1.proveedores_ID = C.proveedores_ID AND C1.partes_ID = P.ID
                                                         )
                                            )
                 );
```

but I could not combine it to generate a query that allows me to return the previously given requirement.
I would appreciate if someone can help me achieve the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

You can join two `NOT EXISTS` conditions with an `OR` to fetch providers for whom there aren't red parts they haven't sold, or there aren't green parts they haven't sold:

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.proveedores_ID FROM fabrica.catalogo C
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                  SELECT P.ID FROM fabrica.partes P
                  WHERE (P.color = "red")
                      AND ( NOT EXISTS (
                          SELECT C1.proveedores_ID FROM fabrica.catalogo C1
                          WHERE C1.proveedores_ID = C.proveedores_ID
                              AND C1.partes_ID = P.ID
                          )
                  )
) OR NOT EXISTS (
                  SELECT P.ID FROM fabrica.partes P
                  WHERE (P.color = "green")
                      AND ( NOT EXISTS (
                          SELECT C1.proveedores_ID FROM fabrica.catalogo C1
                          WHERE C1.proveedores_ID = C.proveedores_ID
                              AND C1.partes_ID = P.ID
                          )
                  )
);
```

Comment: Wouldn't this provide all the suppliers that supply all the parts in red **AND** green rather than all the parts in red **OR** green?

Comment: You're right, I had misinterpreted the question and changed the answer accordingly, but this brings a new question, must it be an exclusive or inclusive `OR`? Should it include providers who have sold both all reds and greens?

Comment: But it is much simpler & clearer to use `WHERE (P.color = "green" OR P.color = 'red')` so why don't you show that too. As long as you have pushed the OR up to the top you could also show a UNION version.

Comment: That is what was done first, but I edited the answer following his first comment. UNION was something I had forgotten about and works too.